# Capturing only part of the string to be recognized in if conditional

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to just capture part of a string in an `if` conditional?

```
var armadilloRoles = [
  { name: 'Billing', description: 'armadillo.organization.billing' },
  { name: 'Doctor', description: 'armadillo.organization.doctor' },
    { name: 'Nurse Practitioner', description: 'armadillo.organization.nursePractitioner' },
  { name: 'Patient', description: 'armadillo.organization.patient' },
  { name: 'Aluna admin', description: 'armadillo.microurb.admin' },
    { name: 'Aluna billing', description: 'armadillo.microurb.billing' },
    { name: 'Respiratory therapist', description: 'armadillo.microurb.respiratoryTherapist' },
    { name: 'Aluna commercial contact', description: 'armadillo.microurb.practiceGrowthDirector' }
];

var viewRoles = [];

for (var i = 0; i < armadilloRoles.length; i++) {
    if (armadilloRoles[i].description === 'armadillo.organization.') {
    viewRoles.push(armadilloRoles[i]);
  }
}

viewRoles;
```

Comment: [`String#startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith), [`String#includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes), [`String#endsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith), [`String#search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search)

Comment: @pilchard, I tried `armadilloRoles.startsWith('armadillo.organization.')` and I get its not a function.

Comment: `armadilloRoles` is an array, not a string. `armadilloRoles[i].description.startsWith('armadillo.organization.')`

Comment: `viewRoles =  armadilloRoles.filter((a) => a.description.startsWith('armadillo.organization.'));`

Comment: @pilchard, I get `TypeError: armadilloRoles[i].startsWith is not a function`

Comment: `armadilloRoles[i]` is an object not a string. As noted in my earlier comment: `armadilloRoles[i].description.startsWith('armadillo.organization.')`

Comment: @pilchard, interesting, now I just get an empty array.

Comment: Working fine for me with your snippet: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/faL6hxq5/)

Comment: @pilchard, I ran it through a diff checker, now I see what was different, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several string methods which could be employed. In your case, you're searching for a substring at the beginning of matching description strings, so the [`.startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) method will work just fine.

```js
var armadilloRoles = [
  { name: 'Billing', description: 'armadillo.organization.billing' },
  { name: 'Doctor', description: 'armadillo.organization.doctor' },
  { name: 'Nurse Practitioner', description: 'armadillo.organization.nursePractitioner' },
  { name: 'Patient', description: 'armadillo.organization.patient' },
  { name: 'Aluna admin', description: 'armadillo.microurb.admin' },
  { name: 'Aluna billing', description: 'armadillo.microurb.billing' },
  { name: 'Respiratory therapist', description: 'armadillo.microurb.respiratoryTherapist' },
  { name: 'Aluna commercial contact', description: 'armadillo.microurb.practiceGrowthDirector' }
];

var viewRoles = [];

for (var i = 0; i < armadilloRoles.length; i++) {
  if (armadilloRoles[i].description.startsWith('armadillo.organization.')) {
    viewRoles.push(armadilloRoles[i]);
  }
}

console.log(viewRoles);
```